# How can I correctly throw an exception when a class is being destroyed?

Tags: c#, exception, destructor, idisposable

I'd like to employ the IDisposable pattern in my C# class so I can wrap it in a 'using block' later on. My issue is that, when the class is getting disposed, I want to be able to throw an exception sometimes if a specific condition isn't met.

I know I can technically throw an exception in either the Dispose method or the class's destruction but it seems, this is discouraged, as per [this Microsoft post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1065-do-not-raise-exceptions-in-unexpected-locations?view=vs-2019)

```cs
class PersonListBuilder : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>();

    public PersonListBuilder SetName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public PersonListBuilder SetAge(int age)
    {
        _age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public PersonListBuilder Push()
    {
        _persons.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = _name,
            Age = _age,
        }
        PrepareForNewPerson();
    }

    public List<Person> Build()
    {
        //Because of other implementation details, I cannot call method 'ThrowExceptionIfUnPushedPersonExists' here
        return _persons;
    }

    private void PrepareForNewPerson()
    {
        _name = string.Empty;
        _age = default;
    }

    private void ThrowExceptionIfUnPushedPersonExists()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name) || age != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Seems there is an unpushed person");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Call below method here is discouraged :(
        ThrowExceptionIfUnPushedPersonExists()
    }
}

class PersonBuilderConsumer
{

    public void MakePersons()
    {
        //What I'd like to do
        try
        {
            using(var personListBuilder = new PersonListBuilder())
            {
                //We won't call the 'Push' method below, so an exception will be throw
                var persons = personListBuilder.SetName("Jane")
                    .SetAge(36)
                    .Build();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // unpushed person exception should get thrown then handled here
        }
    } 
}
```

Ideally, I would like to use the code as is show in the sample, but again, as per [this Microsoft post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1065-do-not-raise-exceptions-in-unexpected-locations?view=vs-2019), the 'Dispose' method, is on the list of places where throwing of exceptions is discouraged. Is there a better way to have my builder return expected result when input is valid but fail if input is wrong?

I could of course call make the method 'ThrowExceptionIfUnPushedPersonExists' public and call it myself right before the end of the 'using block', but then am worried that I may forget to do so, which would make the Builder 'untrustworthy'.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is such a confusing code that you really should reconsider your pattern. What is wrong by simply adding a person object to a list, why you need that many extra methods which are related by complicated checking?

Comment: Also `return this;` is returning `PersonListBuilder` while your method signature says it should return `PersonBuilder`. Does this code compile??

Comment: @Aldert I've simplified the actual code to make it possible to ask the questions.  The reason a builder is used instead of directly adding an object to a list,  is because data used to build up the object is assembled across multiple different classes and not all at once. The builder allows, adding data, as it becomes available then finally creates an instance of the object when possible to do so.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Throwing exceptions from `Dispose` would be *deeply* surprising. Take a step back and reconsider how this whole API should work.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, it was a mistake on my part and I've fixed it

Comment: Never, ever throw from `Dispose()`. Just... no.

Comment: Thanks guys. Guess its back to the drawing board. :(